# Как в X11 отследить создание окна другим процессом?

Tags: unix, x11

Мне нужно перехватить в X11 событие создания нового окна другими процессами средствами XLib и получить дескриптор окна. Могу ли я использовать для этого `XNextEvent()`?

Comment: событие [CreateNotify](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/create.html), оно?

Comment: Видимо, да. Однако, главный вопрос в том, получу ли я это событие от другого процесса.

Comment: судя по отсутствию каких-либо оговорок в документации — должен... но стоит проверить...

Comment: Смущает вот это: *"To receive CreateNotify events, set the SubstructureNotifyMask bit in the event-mask attribute of the window. Creating any children then generates an event."*. То есть, я должен применить данную маску к корневому окну?

Comment: мда… звучит как-то не совсем правильно, но на самом деле может и сработать… предсказать результат я не возьмусь, так что надо пробовать…

Answer (score 1):

Эксперимент показал, что для перехвата событий создания окна любым клиентом достаточно следующего:

```
Window rootWin = XRootWindow(disp, 0);     
XSelectInput(disp, rootWin, SubstructureNotifyMask); 
...
while (1) {
    int ret = XNextEvent(disp, &event); 
...
```